# Show that the vector space of real functions is not finitely spanned

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, finitely-generated

Here's what I've come up with. Let $\mathcal B$ be a generating set of $\mathcal F(R)$. Let us assume that $\mathcal B$ is a finite set, thus: $\lt  \mathcal B \gt = \lt \{b_1, ..., b_n \}\gt, n \in N$. Let  $\mathcal f \in F(R).$ Thus: $\mathcal f = \alpha_1 b_1 + ... + \alpha_nb_n,$ where $ \alpha_1,..., \alpha_n \in R$ are not all zeroes.

If  $\mathcal F(R)$ is a vector space, so there can be a function  $\mathcal g \in F(R)$ such as  $\mathcal g \neq \lambda f, \lambda \in R$. Thus  $\mathcal f+g \in F(R)$  but  $\mathcal f+g \neq \alpha_1 b_1 + ... + \alpha_nb_n$. If is $\mathcal g$ is to belong to $ \lt \mathcal B \gt$ we must add a new vector to $\mathcal B$.

Repeating the above mentioned procedure, we can find a function $\mathcal g\in F(R)$ such as $\mathcal h \neq \mathcal\lambda g$. Thus, we can find infinite functions and thus need infinite base vectors.

Is this proof right?

Comment: This proof cannot be right, as it does not exploit in any way the fact that $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb R)$ is the space of functions. With the same proof you could show that *any* vector space is infinite dimensional. The flaw is in the choice of $g$. Even if $g$ is not a multiple of $f$, this does not mean that it cannot be in the linear span of $b_1\ldots b_n$.

Comment: I`ve debated with a friend about this. What if I choose some generic base $\mathcal B$, not one that generates the whole set of $\mathcal F(R)$ but one witch generates one subset space of it? For instance, choosing a base that generates $\mathcal V = \{f(x) \in F(R), f(1) = 0\}$ and then, using one of basis theorems, complete it for $\mathcal F(R)$

Comment: That does not seem to go anywhere, frankly. I just think you are not on the right track. You need to find an infinite linearly independent set of functions, that's all.

Answer (score 3):

I think I understand the spirit of your proof, but it doesn't seem rigorous.

What you are trying to prove is equivalent to saying that $\mathcal{F}(R)$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space (if $\mathcal{F}(R)$ were finite dimensional, any basis would be a finite spanning set). Therefore if we could display an infinite collection of linearly independent vectors, we'd be done.

Can you show that the set $\{1, x, x^2, \dots \}$ is linearly independent?

Comment: Another (easier) option would be to use the functions that are $1$ at exactly one point, and $0$ everywhere else.

Comment: Showing that $\{ 1, x, x^2, ...\}$ is easy, but I don`t understand how that helps me in this case. Would you mind explaining that to me?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pretty silly proof:

Let $S$ be any infinite set, and let $F(S, \mathbb{R})$ be the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space of functions $S \to \mathbb{R}$. Furthermore, let $\mathbb{R}_d [x]$ denote the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space of polynomials in $x$ of degree $\le d$.

Suppose $f_1, \cdots, f_n \in F(S, \mathbb{R})$ is a finite basis.

Choose some $f \in F(S, \mathbb{R})$ that takes on infinitely many values. For each polynomial $p \in \mathbb{R}_d [x]$, we may write $p(f)$ uniquely in the form $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i f_i$ for some real scalars $a_i$. Hence, we get a linear map $\mathbb{R}_d [x] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ given by $$p \mapsto (a_1, \cdots, a_n).$$ In fact, this map is injective, since $p(f) = 0$ implies $p = 0$, given as a polynomial may have only finitely many roots.

Thus, $\dim(\mathbb{R}_d [x]) \le n$ for all $d$; taking $d\to\infty$ gives a contradiction.

Comment: That is indeed a valid proof, but my professor has not instructed us to proof this kind of problems using maps. He`s expecting us to prove using only vector-space related stuff. This is the only reason why I will not accecpt your answer as correct, altough it definately is and it is more intuitive. Thank you for your input Sameer!